# Put variable inside onclick in Javascript

Tags: javascript

See below code,

```
marker = new MarkerWithLabel({
            map: resultsMap,
            position: latlng,
            title: "Address",
            //  radius: int_radius ,
            draggable: false,
            labelAnchor: new google.maps.Point(10, 35),
            labelContent: label,
            labelClass: "labels",
            labelInBackground: false,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
            icon: image,
            customInfo: "<span><strong>"+storename[x]+"</strong></span><br><br><p><strong>Address</strong></p>"+address[x]+
            ',<br>'+city[x]+', '+state[x]+' '+zipcode_true[x]+"<p><strong>Phone</strong></p>"+phone[x]+"<button onclick='redirect();' class='btn btn-brown'>Print Coupon</button>"
    });  
details
                    (    x,
                         address,
                         storename,
                         phone,
                         marker,
                         resultsMap,
                         zipcode_true,
                         city, state,
                        (distance.status == 'NOT_FOUND' ? '' : distance.distance.text));
```

another function ,

```
function details(x, address, storename, phone,marker, resultsMap, zipcode_true, city, state, distance){
// more code
    var dynamic_address = "<li data-index="+new_id+" id='"+new_id+"'  address-wrapper'>"+
                              "<div id='"+emailLinkId+"' class='address-blk'><span class='number'>"+ (x+1) +
                              "</span><span class='marker-name'><a class='store-title' href='#' onclick='openInfoWindow("+resultsMap+");' style='text-decoration: none;'>"+storename[x]+
                              "</a><span>"+distance+"</span></span>";
// more code
}
```

I need to call function with parameters using onclick event.

```
onclick='openInfoWindow("+resultsMap+");'
```

Console says, "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier". How to pass variable in this situation?

Comment: You're missing some quotes: `onclick='openInfoWindow("'+resultsMap+'");'`

Comment: Do you have a function to call? You have a function but don't know how to call it? This `resultMap` is from where? What does the concat string `dynamic_address` got to do with this?

Comment: Are you trying to pass the *value* of `resultsMap` to `openInfoWindow()` as a string, or as a *reference* to `resultsMap`?

Comment: @Andrew L   Now it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string"

Comment: @ BenM  as a reference to resultsMap

Comment: Do you have the other 5 variables?

Comment: @hogard Are you passing `resultsMap` as a variable?

Comment: @hogard Your issue is that `resultsMap` is out of scope for your click function. How is it defined at the moment?

Comment: @BenM see my edited code

Comment: Everything works fine untill I add onclick event to call function in order to open an info window on map

Comment: @hogard Your code is a total mess with all that inline HTML. If your code is a mess, your brain will be a mess, and you will have a really hard time debugging, not to mention adding any new features and functionality. I strongly suggest you invest some time in cleaning up that code, especially using an HTML templating library as I mentioned in my answer. Take it from someone who's done it the hard way, taking time to clean up your code will pay dividends of time and productivity later.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do all of this string building stuff in-line. I could tell you what the bug is in your code, but the real problem is not the bug itself. The problem is that doing this stuff is a huge pain in the ass without the proper tool, and you will always encounter unexpected and pathological bugs, maybe not even right away, maybe 6 weeks down the line in production.

The name of the game here is separating things like syntax errors from semantic errors from logical errors. If you're not using the right tool it can be extremely hard and time-consuming to tease apart these situations, especially as your code grows and becomes more interconnected. On the other hand if you are using the right tool, it will give you errors relevant to the problem you are trying to solve.

If you're constructing some dynamic HTML in javascript, the right tool for your task is a templating library like [Handlebars.js](http://handlebarsjs.com/).

At the very least, if you don't want to use a library, you should construct your string one piece at a time based on logical chunks, and then concatenate the pieces. This will make your code more readable, more writable, and also easier to debug.

Also as of ES6 you can use [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to make string construction much easier.

Comment: @hogard Sorry I won't do that. The right answer to this problem is not to fix your error. The right answer is to use a different approach to HTML templating.